# Getting list of keywords from JSON

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, urllib2

I have encountered a problem and I don't understand why it printed out this way.

Below is my code, please forgive me for the bad formatting as I am new to programming, this is to open a text file which has a bunch of keywords

```
import urllib2
import json

f1 = open('CatList.text')
lines = f1.readlines()

for  line in lines:

    url ='https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle='+line+'&cmlimit=100'

    print(url)

    json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    data = json.load(json_obj)

    #to write the result
    f2 = open('SubList.text', 'w')

    f2.write(url)

    for item in data['query']:

            for i in data['query']['categorymembers']:


                f2.write((i['title']).encode('utf8')+"\n")
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test2.py", line 16, in <module>
    json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 402, in open
    req = meth(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1113, in do_request_
    raise URLError('no host given')
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error no host given>
```

I am not sure what this error means but I tried this to print the url.

```
import urllib2
import json

f1 = open('CatList.text')
f2 = open('SubList.text', 'w')
lines = f1.readlines()

for  line in lines:

    url ='https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle='+line+'&cmlimit=100'

    print(url)
    f2.write(url+'\n')
```

The results I have gotten were weird (below is part of the result):

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Branches of geography
&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geography by place
&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geography awards and competitions
&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geography conferences
&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geography education
&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Environmental studies
&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Exploration
&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geocodes
&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geographers
&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geographical zones
&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geopolitical corridors
&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:History of geography
&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Land systems
&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Landscape
&cmlimit=100
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geography-related lists
&cmlimit=100
```

Notice that the URL is broken up into 2 parts

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geography-related lists
&cmlimit=100
```

instead of

```
  https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Geography-related lists&cmlimit=100
```

**My first question is how can I fix this?**

**Secondly, is this what that is giving me the error?**

My CatList.text is as follows:

```
Category:Branches of geography
Category:Geography by place
Category:Geography awards and competitions
Category:Geography conferences
Category:Geography education
Category:Environmental studies
Category:Exploration
Category:Geocodes
Category:Geographers
Category:Geographical zones
Category:Geopolitical corridors
Category:History of geography
Category:Land systems
Category:Landscape
Category:Geography-related lists
Category:Lists of countries by geography
Category:Navigation
Category:Geography organizations
Category:Places
Category:Geographical regions
Category:Surveying
Category:Geographical technology
Category:Geography terminology
Category:Works about geography
Category:Geographic images
Category:Geography stubs
```

Sorry for the long post. I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Do you get the error with all urls? It might be because there are spaces in the url? I ususally use the _requests_ library for http. It's more user friendly than urllib2.

Comment: I am guessing it is not able to detect because of the URL splitting into 2 line instead of 1, but I have no idea how to fix that part.

Comment: strip spaces from `line`. It's a newline character at the end of the string. `line = line.strip()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the following line

```
url ='https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle='+line+'&cmlimit=100'
```

to

```
url ='https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle='+line.strip()+'&cmlimit=100'
```

Your `line` contains line-feed (`\n`) characters which will be removed using `.strip()` which removes white-spaces from both ends of a string.

Answer (score 2):

Friend, Generally '\n' is used for new line . Same sense , In a file there is hidden '\n' character between each lines.

So at **lines = f1.readlines()** it includes '\n' in end of all lines. This is the problem.

To avoid this, you should read as **f1.read.splitlines()** .

Comment: Hi i tried running that it gives me a weird error  'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'splitlines'.

Comment: please try this., lines =f1.read().split('\n') OR lines= [line[:-1] for line in file]